# Passing int value, .putExtra, loop

Tags: android, android-intent, while-loop, final

I need to pass int value i to other class, because it's the id from a database, but it doesn't allow me to pass the int value using .putExtra, because the value needs to be int, but if I declare that value as final then it can't change anymore for the loop.. Help, thanks.

```
final int x = DataBaseHelper.getLastId();
        int i = 0;

        final TextView[] textViews = new TextView[x];

        while (i < x) {
            TextView newTextView = new TextView(this);
            newTextView.setText(DataBaseHelper.getTitleNow(i + 1) + " \n");
            newTextView.setInputType(newTextView.getInputType() | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
            newTextView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams((LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT), ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            newTextView.setClickable(true);
            newTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent intent = new Intent(HistoryActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("ID", i);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            });
            ll.addView(newTextView, layoutParams); 
            textViews[i] = newTextView;
            i++;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare `i` as a member variable and you can use it in your `onClick()`

```
public class HistoryActivity extends Activity
{
    int i;

    public void onCreate(...)
{
   ...
}

final int x = DataBaseHelper.getLastId();  //not sure where all of this code is but take off the int type here
    i = 0;

    final TextView[] textViews = new TextView[x];

    while (i < x) {
```

Just declare it outside of a function (usually right after the class definition) then it is available everywhere within the `Activity`

You also could use another variable within the loop to assign to `i` as a `final` variable

```
 while (i < x) {
        final int j = i;  // use new variable here 
        TextView newTextView = new TextView(this);
       ...
        newTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(HistoryActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("ID", j);  // use newly defined variable
                startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: before, i tried to define a new final int j variable but it didn't workt, now it works, lol. Thanks.

Comment: I can't say for sure without seeing what you had but I would assume you had it outside of the `while loop`. Being inside the `loop` it gets reinitialized every iteration where outside it is only initialized once so it can't be changed. Glad you have it working now :)